How do I sort customer column by name?
Does odoo 16 offer the option of sorting the customer list alphabetically in ascending or descending order? In the module res.partner (view_type=list) I can sort the entries by all columns, but not by name. Is this a setting in the configuration or do I have to create a module extension somewhere that then generates a corresponding “Name” field for sorting?

That's because the column is a computed non-stored field and only stored fields can be sorted. So you have atleast to easy possibilities:

Make the field stored.

class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.partner"

    translated_display_name = fields.Char(store=True)

If you use more than one language in Odoo, i wouldn't do that, because otherwise Company invoice, delivery and other addresses without name would never be translated again after saving.

Change the list column from field translated_display_name to display_name, because the second is already stored in database.


Thanks! This gave me the idea of creating a small module in which this field is added and the translated_display_name is hidden:
<xpath expr="//tree/field[1]" position="before">   <field name="name"/> </xpath> <xpath expr="//field[@name='translated_display_name']" position="replace"/>
